# cx_Freeze : Importing modules fails

Tags: python, module, compilation, cx-freeze

I would like to compile a Python3 project with cx_Freeze, but no matter what I do I can never import my own `.py` files.

Here's my directory structure:

```
projectname/
 setup.py
 app/
    code/
       __init__.py
       config.py
       run.py
       run - editeur.py
       ... 
    image/
       ...
    level/
       ...
```

My `setup.py` :

```
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path = sys.path
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ["app/code"]
includefiles = ["app/image", "app/level"]

optimize = 0
silent = True

options = {"path": path,
       "includes": includes,
       "excludes": excludes,
       "packages": packages,
       "include_files": includefiles,
       "optimize": optimize,
       "silent": silent
       }

base = Win32GUI

cible_1 = Executable(
    script="app/code/run.py",
    )

cible_2 = Executable(
    script="app/code/run - editeur.py",
    )

setup(
    name="project",
    version="1.0",
    description="blabla",
    options={"build_exe": options},
    executables=[cible_1, cible_2]
    )
```

The cx_Freeze compilation is going well and I get my 2 executables. 
But when I try to launch one, every time I get the same error:

```
[...]
File "app/code/run.py", line 7, in <module>
import config
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

I really have to miss something stupid since I have no problem with the plug-ins.
It may also be a problem of path or something else I don't know...

Anyone know how to help me a little ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've managed to freeze a simplified example based on your directory structure with the following modification of the `setup.py` script:

```py
path = sys.path + ['app/code']
packages = []
```

Alternatively, you could also try the following structure (modifying the import paths accordingly):

```
projectname/
   setup.py
   config.py
   run.py
   run - editeur.py
   ... 
   image/
      ...
   level/
      ...
```

Comment: No sadly it doesn't work ... keep saying the same awser, I don't know why.
I finnaly manage to get a correct working executable version, but mixing and moving files of the compiled version into the "normal" one.

Comment: @Bablup After some additional testing I think I've found a way to solve your problem without the need of any mixing and moving after freezing. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah thank's it's better, but still not perfect... Now the code files are loaded correctly but, can't access to the image folder.
`File "app/code/run.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "app/code\config.py", line 36, in init
pygame.error: Couldn't open ../image/sol.png`
I tried to put them in includefiles = [], creating a _init_ (whatever it could do) or specify the all "app" folder in sys.path, but it just don't work ...

Comment: I think you need to move the resource folders `image` and `level` into the same folder as the main scripts at least for the frozen application, because otherwise these folders would be outside of the installaion directory. But you could have different relative locations for the unfrozen and frozen application using the mechanism described in the [Using data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) section of the cx_Freeze documentation.